# Show that : $ \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\xrightarrow[x \to a]{} l \implies \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\xrightarrow[x \to a]{} l\quad (l\in \mathbb{\bar{R}}) $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

Let $f$,$g\in \mathcal{C}((a,b),\mathbb{R})$ are differentiable on $(a,b)$

- we assume that $f(a)=g(a)=0$ and $g'\neq  0  $ on $(a,b)$

Show that $$ \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\xrightarrow[x \to a]{} l \implies \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\xrightarrow[x \to a]{} l\quad  (l\in \mathbb{\bar{R}}) $$

My thoughts

by Cauchy's mean value theorem : $\exists\ C\in (a,b)$ such that $\left(f(b)-f(a)\right)g'(c)=\left(g(a)-g(b)\right)f'(c)$

since $g'\neq 0$ then $\dfrac{f(b) - f(a)}{g(b) - g(a)} = \dfrac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}.$

or $f(a)=g(a)=0$ then $\dfrac{f(b)}{g(b)} = \dfrac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}.$

i want to use L'Hôpitals rule but i'm stuck

Comment: You surely can't use L'Hôpital's rule to prove this, as this is a weaker version of L'Hôpital.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly 
$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{g(x) -g(a)}.$$

For each $x > a$, use Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem on $(a,x)$ to say that there exists $c = c(x) \in (a,x)$ such that $\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} = \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x) - g(a)}$. Notice that $c(x) \to a$ as $x \to a$, so that

$$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{g(x) -g(a)} = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f'(c(x))}{g'(c(x))} = \lim_{c \to a} \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} = l$$

Comment: is that means we don't need to use cauchy's mean value theorem and then $$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{g(x) -g(a)} = \lim_{x \to a} \left(\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} \cdot \frac{x-a}{g(x) - g(a)}\right)=\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

Comment: We need to use Cauchy's MVT for that last step (I've added this to the post)

Comment: we can't say directly by def of limit that $\lim_{x \to a} \left(\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} \cdot \frac{x-a}{g(x) - g(a)}\right)=\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} $

Comment: I don't think so, at least not without some manipulations which would essentially prove Cauchy's MVT.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I realized that there was no need for the last step, just apply the MVT directly.

Comment: i can't see ur proof (Since c(x)→a as x→a, we're done. ) could you add more details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20438/discussion-between-pedro-m-and-educ).

Answer (score -1):

As $f(a)=0$ & $g(a)=0$ & $g'(a)\not =0$ so by L'Hospital rule,$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=l.$$

Comment: Why down-voting?