# Find the value of $\lim _{x\to \:1+}\left(\frac{\sin \left(\pi x\right)}{\ln \left(x\right)}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Compute this limit by applying this question [Show that : $ \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\xrightarrow[x \to a]{} l \implies \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\xrightarrow[x \to a]{} l\quad (l\in \mathbb{\bar{R}}) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1113930/fracfxgx-xrightarrowx-to-a-l-implies-fracfxgx-xright/1113939#1113939)

$$\lim _{x\to \:1+}\left(\frac{\sin \left(\pi x\right)}{\ln \left(x\right)}\right)$$

My thoughts:

$\lim _{x\to \:1+}\left(\frac{\sin \left(\pi x\right)}{\ln \left(x\right)}\right)$

Applying l'hopital rule:

$=\lim _{x\to \:1+}\left(\frac{\cos \left(\pi x\right)\pi }{\frac{1}{x}}\right)$
$=\lim _{x\to \:1+}\left(\pi x\cos \left(\pi x\right)\right)$
$=\pi \lim _{x\to \:1+}\left(x\right)\lim _{x\to \:1+}\left(\cos \left(\pi x\right)\right)$
$=\pi 1\left(-1\right)$
$=-\pi $

but if we want to apply question which i think is weaker version of hopital rule how we gonna do

Comment: The question in the link is about proving a case of l'Hospital's rule, so you did it alright.

Comment: You did use the weaker version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I should have written this in a comment, but it is a bit too long. Since the hypothesis of De l'Hôpital's rule (Bernoulli Theorem) are a bit awkward and difficult to remember, many mathematicians prefer to completely avoid it and use Taylor expansions with Peano remainders, instead. In this case, since in a neighbourhood of the origin:
$$\sin z=z+o(z^2),\qquad \log(1+z)=z-\frac{z^2}{2}+o(z^2), $$
we have:
$$ \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\log(x)}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{-\sin(\pi z)}{\log(1+z)}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{-\pi z + o(z^2)}{z+O(z^2)}=\color{red}{-\pi}, $$
without explicitly differentiating any function.

Comment: but you didn't told me am i right ?

Comment: @Educ: I agree with user121591, you did use the weak version.